# Adapt the length of UITableViewCell to that of the UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswitch

It is my first swift project and I try to make an in app settings page.
So I have a basic UITabelView with custom UITableViewCell inside. My UITableViewCell contains a UILabel on the left and a UISwitch on the right.

the problem is that the UITableViewCell length is static (I think) and when I compile on my iPhone 6 plus this is the result :

[image]

And when I compile on a iPad air simulator I don't have my cells.

So how adapt the UItableViewCell length dynamically ?

Comment: it looks like your not using autolayout ?

Comment: No i don't use ? I must ?

Comment: Are you set the layout constraint

Comment: you don't need to, but you should. you can do it with springs+struts but auto layout is the future...

Comment: Ok I will read the doc of the auto layout, Thanks

Comment: By the way, the problem is not in cell itself – it always has the same width as table, but in layout of cell's subviews.

Comment: Thanks it's works well !!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to fix it.

In your TableCell.m

Add this when you creating the UISwitch

Objective-c:

```
switch.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
```

Swift :

```
switch.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleLeftMargin;
```